# Joining two tables in SQL while checking with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
SELECT *, (`expire_date` IS NULL) AS `permanent` 
FROM `player_bans` 
WHERE (`ip` = '%e' OR `userid` = '%d') AND 
    (`expire_date` > NOW() OR `expire_date` IS NULL) 
LIMIT 1
```

I have a table called "players" and the "player_bans" table has a "by_userid" column. This indicates by whom the player has been banned by. The by_userid column in the player_bans table is related to the ID (unique insert ID) in the players table. The players table also has a Username field, which I want to fetch by using the query above.

So, the query must find the banning user's name from the players table, by looking at the by_userid field in the player_bans table.

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN`, try this:

```
SELECT pb.*, (`expire_date` IS NULL) AS `permanent`, p.username AS `banned by`
FROM `player_bans` pb JOIN players p ON pb.by_userid = p.id
WHERE (`pb.ip` = '%e' OR `pb.userid` = '%d') AND 
    (`expire_date` > NOW() OR `pb.expire_date` IS NULL) 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying.
I have an error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'pb.expire_date' in 'field list'

Comment: Removed `pb.`, try now? Also, could you make sure `expire_date` exists in `player_bans` table?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the query according to my needs, since the WHERE clause (ip and userid) are already a user input, there is no need for them to have pb. and pb.expire_date was also not going to work. So I edited the query and it worked. Here's what I did:

SELECT pb.*, (`expire_date` IS NULL) AS `permanent`, p.username AS `banned by`
FROM `player_bans` pb JOIN players p ON pb.by_userid = p.id
WHERE (`ip` = '%e' OR `userid` = '%d') AND 
    (`expire_date` > NOW() OR `expire_date` IS NULL) 
LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query :

```
SELECT t1.*, (`t1.expire_date` IS NULL) AS `permanent`,t2.username 
FROM `player_bans` as t1 INNER JOIN  `players` as t2 
ON t1.by_userid=t2.id
and (`ip` = '%e' OR `userid` = '%d') AND 
    (`expire_date` > NOW() OR `expire_date` IS NULL) 
LIMIT 1
```